# How to get Active user and place in a specific cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue with this code it runs from the script editor and writes the data correctly but when editing the cell where the trigger is, it doesn't run, only for the owner of the sheet and script it works could someone tell me why this is, please?

It should be straight forward but cannot get it to work.

Furthermore, the user have their names added as a contact.

```
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var fullName = ContactsApp.getContact(email).getFullName();

function setTimeDateUser() {

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = spreadSheet.getActiveCell();
  var getRow = activeCell.getRow();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 ){ 

    var date = activeCell.offset(0, 1);      
    date.setValue(new Date());

    var userName = activeCell.offset(0, 2);
    userName.setValue(fullName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do think editing a cell will trigger your function?  There must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: Apologies I set setTimeDateUser() as an installable trigger as onEdit() didn't work. My guess is that it is accessible by anyone, setTimeDateUser() is accessible by only those who allow it.

Comment: There's already a built-in edit history for each cell.  It doesn't work because installable triggers runs as the user who created the trigger and not the active user. Only way it may even work is by creating a installable trigger for each user and seeing if active user= effective user in those scripts. This needs permission for each of those users.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible in the way you would want it because, as the documentation for  [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) says in its restrictions:

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the
>   spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

And for [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) the restrictions say:

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who
>   created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger,
>   it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has
>   edit access), but it runs as your account. This means that if you
>   create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the email
>   is always be sent from your account, not necessarily the account that
>   opened the document. However, you could create an installable trigger
>   for each account, which would result in one email sent from each
>   account.

And for more info about Event Objects, you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).